# Show all running node.js scripts using bash

Tags: command-line, process, node.js

To find a python script, I use `pgrep -af python`.

Is there a similar command to find node.js scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
pgrep -a node
```

This could potentially detect false positives if you have another process with node in its name.

---

Also note this wouldn't work if the node script is using a node hashbang and was run without the node command, although I think that would also be the case for python scripts.

Comment: Just a quick query. If the name of the process is 'node', and you don't want to search the full command line with arguments, why not do `pgrep -a node` instead?

Comment: @Haxiel: Good point.  That could also detect false positives but should be essentially the same as the awk commands I've included anyway